# Selenium webdriver: Unable to key into Search box

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am automating a test on a web app. In one of the page, there is a Search text box, and is denoted by

`<input data-v-14e134a3="" type="text" placeholder="Search" id="form-search-catalog" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" class="form-input form-input--outline font-weight-light text-center form-search-catalog">`

The xpath and full xpath respectively for that Search element are as follow :

`//*[@id="form-search-catalog"]`

`/html/body/div/main/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/input`

I tried using the code below :

```
1: driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/main/div/div/div/div[1]/input")).click(); // click on the Search textbox to highlight it
2: driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/main/div/div/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("ABC");//Send the text "ABC" to the Search textbox
```

The result was that the L1 itself return error `element not interactable`

Then I tried with the following code

```
1: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
2: WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("form-search-catalog")));
3: driver.findElement(By.id("form-search-catalog")).sendKeys("ABC");
```

The result was a return of error `Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: form-search-catalog`

The Search textbox is clearly present in the web app UI.

Hope to have advice on what mistake I have commit.

Note: The Search box on the web app shown below
[image]

Comment: It is present on the visible portion of the screen and is it in enabled state when you are trying to interact with it?

Comment: Make sure to check if the required search box is inside any <iframe>. Moreover, you can check whatever is visible to the driver by using 'driver.getPageSource()' method and evaluate the HTML.

Comment: @lshan, thanks for your comment. I have just attached a screenshot of the search textbox which is visible, if that is what you mean. Also, may I know how to check whether it is enabled state ?

Comment: @Ayaz, thanks. I shall try that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using Actions class.

```
Actions a=new Actions(driver);
WebElement weText=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/main/div/div/div/div[1]/input"));
a.moveToElement(weText).click().build().perform();
Thread.sleep(3000);
weText.sendKeys("ABC");
```

It would be much more helpful if u can share the html page link. But I'm positive that above solution will work if your xpath is absolutely correct

Comment: Thanks ! your solution works ! But why doesn't the normal .click() work compared to using the Action class ? By the way, does the Action class works for mobile app as well ? Thanks for your advice !

Comment: @Dish I am facing exactly the same problem. I am unable to click on the result found through search box and redirect the page

Answer (score 1):

Try using Javascript executer

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```